# Is there a 'finally' pattern for Promises?

Tags: javascript, promise

Imagine the following Promise-based example:

```
function treadLightly() {
  return Promise.resolve()
    .then(function() { allocateResource(); })
    .then(function() { doRiskyOperation(); })
    .then(function() { releaseResource(); })
    .catch(function() { releaseResource(); })
  ;
}
```

We want to call `releaseResource()` whether or not `doRiskyOperation()` resolves or rejects.  But there's a whiff of code smell in calling `releaseResource()` in two separate places.

What we really want is something equivalent to javascript's `finally`.

Is there a cleaner way to code this in Promises?

Comment: Worth reading this article about [resource management using promises](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/resource-management.html) where even `.finally()` is not always the perfect choice and it discusses a design pattern using disposers.

Comment: Why do you start a promise chain with `Promise.resolve().then(function() { allocateResource(); }).then(...)` instead of `allocateResource().then(...)`?  If `allocateResource()` isn't async, then why is it in the promise chain?

Comment: @jfriend00: Because it's a good pattern :).  `allocateResource()` may or may not return a promise, and you won't know unless can look at its code.  Starting a chain with `Promise.resolve()` makes the chain insensitive to what `allocateResource()` returns, and (more importantly) makes the intention clear.

Comment: If you're calling code that you don't know whether it's async or not and don't know whether or not it returns a promise - remind me never to use any software you've written.  That's just irresponsible programming.  It's not a good design pattern to program blind or needlessly wrap things in `Promise.resolve()` that don't need to be.

Comment: @jfriend00: we should simply disagree (rather than be disagreeable): If the called function already has the desired value, you can return it directly, else return a Promise that resolves later. Yes, you could always return `Promise.resolve(desiredValue)`, but it's not clear why or if that's better than what's posted above.

Comment: Well, typically you execute your synchronous function first and then pass it's return value to the first async function which you just call directly.  There's no benefit to wrapping a synchronous function in a promise.  I took strong exception to you trying to defend "not knowing" what your function was returning.  That's no defense and never, ever a good idea.  If you like extra, unnecessary wrapping of functions in `Promise.resolve()`, that's your choice.  That doesn't make it a good design pattern.

Comment: Not to flog a dead horse, but I adopted some of my style from http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_promises.html -- search for "25.10.2.2 Solution 2: executing the sync code inside a callback" and they espouse starting a chain with `Promise.resolve()`.  De gustibus non disputandum est, etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although [@T.J. Crowder's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41364657/1597872) is correct, a practical solution to your issue can be adding another `.then` at the end:

```
function treadLightly() {
  return Promise.resolve()
    .then(function() { allocateResource(); })
    .then(function() { doRiskyOperation(); })
    .catch(function() { /* Do nothing, or log the error */ })
    .then(function() { releaseResource(); })
  ;
}
```

Comment: Glad to know there's a .finally in the works (and @T.J. Crowder gets +1 for the polyfill).  But in the meantime, this answers the OP elegantly.  Thanks...

Comment: @fearless_fool: This works fine in an isolated example, but fairly quickly degrades in non-trivial real-world situations. So yes, absolutely, has some use, but beware that converting a rejection into a resolution (which is what this does) is misleading to subsequent handlers.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: duly noted -- thank you.  I'm mulling a general approach that captures the error, invokes the cleanup method (e.g. releaseResource()) and then re-rejects the error, exactly to avoid misleading subsequent handlers. Or I could just implement the polyfill!

Answer (score 5):

ES2015 (ES6) promises don't have `finally` **yet**. There's a [Stage 2 proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-promise-finally) for it, which means there's basically no chance of it being in ES2017 but some possibility of it being in ES2018. I haven't seen a really good *pattern* (as opposed to an actual `finally` feature) for it.

Some third-party promise libraries have it, including [Bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/finally.html), [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#promisefinallycallback), and [when](https://github.com/cujojs/when/blob/master/docs/api.md#promisefinally). jQuery's Deferred's promises also have it, in the form of [`always`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR).

The proposal has a [polyfill](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-promise-finally/blob/master/polyfill.js) you can use:

```
if (typeof Promise !== 'function') {
    throw new TypeError('A global Promise is required');
}

if (typeof Promise.prototype.finally !== 'function') {
    var speciesConstructor = function (O, defaultConstructor) {
        var C = typeof O.constructor === 'undefined' ? defaultConstructor : O.constructor;
        var S = C[Symbol.species];
        return S == null ? defaultConstructor : S;

        var C = O.constructor;
        if (typeof C === 'undefined') {
            return defaultConstructor;
        }
        if (!C || (typeof C !== 'object' && typeof C !== 'function')) {
            throw new TypeError('O.constructor is not an Object');
        }
        var S = C[Symbol.species];
        if (S == null) {
            return defaultConstructor;
        }
        if (typeof S === 'function' && S.prototype) {
            return S;
        }
        throw new TypeError('no constructor found');
    };
    var shim = {
        finally(onFinally) {
            var handler = typeof onFinally === 'function' ? onFinally : () => {};
            var C;
            var newPromise = Promise.prototype.then.call(
                this, // throw if IsPromise(this) is not true
                x => new C(resolve => resolve(handler())).then(() => x),
                e => new C(resolve => resolve(handler())).then(() => { throw e; })
            );
            C = speciesConstructor(this, Promise); // throws if SpeciesConstructor throws
            return newPromise;
        }
    };
    Promise.prototype.finally = shim.finally;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a 'finally' pattern for Promises?

Not through the native (ES6) implementations. However, [Bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api-reference.html) has this feature:

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    ...
}).finally(() => {
    ...
});
```

[.finally | bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/finally.html)